# Print full screen overlays fully top to bottom without scrolling

Tags: css, printing, overlay

As the title, I was trying to create a CSS print style-sheet and encountered this problem. When I tried to print a full-screen overlay with scrollable content, only the content displayed will be printed and the non-displayed content is somewhat ignored. I was wondering how to tweak the print mode with CSS so the full-screen overlay will have the same behavior as a regular page(the full content will be printed no matter if it's currently on display)

Comment: can your add your css samples ?

Answer (score 1):

as you said you're on an overlay, your html's body tag could have scrolling disabled and position fixed.

```
// You need to remove below css properties
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your overlay is an img or div with `background-image` set.
You could modify its positioning rules only if the page gets printed with the media-rule

```
@print {
    /*css code on print*/
}
```

and the positioning for filling the eitire screen is possible with:

```
position: absolute; /*maybe try "fixed"*/
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: But that means only the first page of the overlay gets printed, what if there are multiple pages of content to print?